# finger print javascript libraries uniqueness

Tags: javascript, fingerprint

Do libraries like client.js or fingerprint.js return unique values constantly or do they vary in time since multiple parameters are taken into consideration to generate the fingerprint?

I'm creating a web app that has to identify the user from his browser without any input and was considering this choice.

Comment: *Libraries like* isn't very helpful. Which library exactly? They will all probblay be different

Answer (score 0):

They will always return the same output based on the exact same combination of inputs. Since they have A LOT of inputs these might vary once the user alters his inputs. These can be stuff like, installing new fonts, installing add ons, changing browser etc.. You should easily find a list of inputs that the specific library uses to find out approximately how easily these will change. Since there are so many, to make the identification as accurate as possibly you really shouldn't use it to identify your users.